# Android: Getting a Service's Messenger after starting it from an Activity

Tags: android, service, android-service

I'm using Messengers to communicate between my activities and service.

When I start a service using `bindService()`, I can get the service's Messenger through the IBinder that's returned. However, I don't see an obvious way to get the service's Messenger if I start my service using `startService()` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> However, I don't see an obvious way to get the service's Messenger if I start my service using startService() instead.

Use `startService()` to send commands to the service. You can call this as many times as is necessary. Supply the activity's `Messenger` via an `Intent` extra. This way, you do not need the service to have its own `Messenger`, let alone need to get that Messenger to the activity.